# What's the difference between og description and meta description?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, meta-description, open-graph-protocol

Should we have both for better SEO? Does having og description, override meta name description?

Comment: See also on StackOverflow: [SEO META TAG og:description vs description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173163/seo-meta-tag-ogdescription-vs-description) (Which should be closed there because this is the correct place to ask questions like this.)

Answer (score 11):

***Meta Description = Search Engines, OG Descriptions = Social Platforms***

Meta Description is used by Search Engines Bots, while the OG (The Open Graph protocol) is used by Social Media Bots, therefore if you want 'extra' information on Social Media sites then you should opt to use both the META and OG tags. You can find a list of whom uses OG below.

> [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29067915/1892635)
>
> [The Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) is supported by a wide range of social
>   platforms which includes:
>
> 1. [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph)
> 2. [Pinterest Developers](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/overview/)
> 3. [Linkedin](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)
> 4. [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started#opengraph)
> 5. [Google Plus](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)